# Find the maximum value of:$3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{c^2-3a^2}{6}}-2\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca}{3}}$

Tags: inequality, wolfram-alpha

Let $a,b,c \in R$, find the maximum value of:$$3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{c^2-3a^2}{6}}-2\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca}{3}}$$

I have the solution:

$$5a^2+2b^2+c^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=5(a-\frac{b+c}{5})^2+\frac{1}{5}(3b-2c)^2\geqslant 0$$

which is equivalent to

$$ a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca\geqslant \frac{c^2-3a^2}{2}$$

or

$$ 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca}{3}}\geqslant 2\sqrt{\frac{c^2-3a^2}{6}}$$

Now, let $x=\sqrt[6]{\dfrac{c^2-3a^2}{6}}$ and the problem is find the maximum value of $P=3t^2-2t^3$, which is easy.

My question:

1. Is there any other solution to this problem?
2. I try to test it on [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=maximize+3%28%7B%5Cdfrac%7Bc%5E2-3a%5E2%7D%7B6%7D%7D%29%5E%281%2F3%29-2%5Csqrt%7B%5Cdfrac%7Ba%5E2%2Bb%5E2%2Bc%5E2-ab-bc-ca%7D%7B3%7D%7D), the result is that the maximum value does not exist. Why ? Is Wolfram Alpha's algorithm wrong or does it use a special calculation method?

Comment: I edited, the result in WA didn't change

Comment: I don't know, but I guess WA gives no output maybe because the square root it gives can be negative...?

Comment: For WA: Introducing $x, y$ for $c^2 - 3a^2 = 6x^3$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - ab - bc - ca = 3y^2, y \ge 0$, we can get global maximum. In detail, maximize[{3*x- 2*y, c^2-3*a^2 = 6*x^3, a^2+b^2+c^2-a * b-b * c-c * a = 3*y^2, y>=0}, {a, b, c, x, y}].

Answer (score 2):

Alternate approach:

$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca$ takes its max value when $b =\frac{a+c}2$. So $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=\frac 34(a-c)^2$, so we aim to maximize

$$3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{c^2-3a^2}{6}}- |c-a|$$

Let $c-a=t$, so $c^2-3a^2=(a+t)^2-3a^2=-2a^2+2at+t^2$. This takes maximum if $a=t/2$, and $c^2-3a^2=3/2 t^2$. Therefore, we aim to maximize

$$3\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{t^2}{4}}-|t|$$

And this takes the maximum when $t=2$, and the maximum value is $1$.

Comment: This took me a while to understand, so this comment is to explain for people who are a bit slow like me. The first term is independent of $b$ so we can maximise the second term on its own. It has a minus sign so we actually want to minimize the expression in the square root. We can write $a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca=(b-\frac{a+c}{2})^2+[\text{something}]$ and this is minimized when $b=\frac{a+c}{2}$.